# Android HorizontalScrollView disable touch handling but allow child get events

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview, android-scrollview

I have a case which includes 3 `ScrollViews` stacked following way:

`HorizontalScrollView` on top and it contains layout, which has `ScrollView`, which contains layout containing another `HorizontalScrollView`.

HorizontalScrollView

--------ScrollView

------------HorizontalScrollView

Without the top `HorizontalScrollView` touch event's work okay, and now I need to disable the top `HorizontalScrollView`, but allow the child's get events normally, child `HorizontalScrollView` will eventually scroll the top `HorizontalScrollView`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am not very clear regarding what you want to do but, this should work,

```
OnTouchListener skipTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //do nothing
            return false;
        }
};
yourView.setOnTouchListener(skipTouchListener);
```

This way `yourView` will not process the touch events.

Comment: Overriding my custom class onTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent to return false, seemed to do the trick.